# Command 'SFDX: Run Apex Tests' resulted in an error (command 'sfdx.force.apex.test.run' not found)

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I am learning Salesforce Apex development by taking a trailhead tutorial.

Tutorial: [Find and Fix Bugs with Apex Replay Debugger](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/find-and-fix-bugs-with-apex-replay-debugger)

I followed the tutorial along and got the following error when I try to call "SFDX: Run Apex Tests" in Visual Studio Code.

> Command 'SFDX: Run Apex Tests' resulted in an error (command
> 'sfdx.force.apex.test.run' not found)

[image]

[image]

I am able to run the tests in a terminal by the way.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance.

---

Added on 2021/11/30

I wonder if it has anything to do with the M1 chip.

My environment:

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
- macOS Big Sur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question.

Everything works fine after I added Java home setting in setting.json of VS Code.

> "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home":
> "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.12/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home",